# Restricting a special character in a text and allowing the same character only after a comma using Regular expression

Tags: regex

My text should start with $ and then can contain only alphabets A-Z, no special character is allowed, now there can be a COMMA (,) and again the same pattern will repeat i.e. $ and alphabets.

How do I create a regular expression for such condition?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: When you mean the same pattern, do you mean a string which is matched by the same pattern, or exactly what was found by the previous match? Ie, is `$A,$B` legal or illegal? Also, can there be more than two repetitions (ie, `$A,$B,$C`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
^\$[A-Z]*,?\$[A-Z]*
```

Detail :

- `^\$` : start with a '$'
- `[A-Z]*` : Char(s) from A to Z
- `,?` : Can have a ','

---

**Edit** after more information :

```
^\$[a-z]*(?:,? ?\$[a-z]*)*$
```

Will match `$adbdfd,$asdfaf` and `$adbdfd` but not `$adbdfd,aa` or `adbdfd,$aa`.

Comment: This will match `$A$A` since you make only the comma optional

Comment: Yes but "there can be a COMMA (,) and again the same pattern" is not really clear.

Comment: I need the following pattern $adbdfd, $asdfaf where the comma and further text is optional, and also the $ shud not be allowed in the text part.

Comment: @user1970629 please edit your question and add examples of valid and invalid inputs (see also the question I asked)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^(?i)(\$[a-z]+)(,(?1))*$
```

or if whitespaces are allowed between comma and the following word, try this

```
^(?i)(\$[a-z]+)(,\s*(?1))*$
```

Comment: Recursive regex is a bit over the top here. The support for recursive pattern is also quite limited.